# Is it possible to change the value of a let variable that is defined as the difference between two other variables, 1 let and 1 const?

Tags: javascript, variables

This is my example.

```
const birthYear = 1966;
let currentYear = 2021;

let age = currentYear - birthYear;
console.log(age);

currentYear = 2025;
console.log(currentYear);
console.log(age);
```

This is a screenshot of the console result. The first console.log(age) returns 55. The second console.log(age) also returns 55. My expectation was that after mutating the value of currentYear to 2025 it would also change the second console.log(age) to 59.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of `age` has not been reassigned after the value of `currentYear` is updated.
You can achieve what you are doing by defining the age as a function.

```
const birthYear = 1966;
let currentYear = 2021;

let age = () => (currentYear - birthYear);
console.log(age());

currentYear = 2025;
console.log(currentYear);
console.log(age());
```

Comment: This answer helped me to do what I was trying to do : )

Comment: glad that it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript does not work this way.
Your variable `age` is assigned the **value** of `currentYear - birthYear` which is `55`.

In fact `age` is not aware where its value come from. It's literally the same as doing `let age = 55`

Comment: This answer helps me to better understand what a variable is and what assignment is doing : )

Answer (score 0):

Here is a much simpler way. Just re-calculate age again and pass it to the variable **age**, since till you re-calculate age, the variable age still holds its previous value which is **55**

```
const birthYear = 1966;
let currentYear = 2021;

let age = currentYear - birthYear;
console.log(age);

currentYear = 2025;
console.log(currentYear);
// now currentYear is 2025 here
age = currentYear - birthYear;
console.log(age);
```

Comment: I guess the difference between the previous answer and this answer is - in the first example, the variable age is a function that calculates the value of age each time it is called so as the currentYear variable changes each year, the age function will still work.

Comment: In the second example, the age variable stores a value so as the currentYear changes, I would have to re-assign the variable each time. What do you think? Thanks! : )

Comment: This answer helps me think about what I am trying to do and how to best solve the challenge : )